# NumberPicker - array of String with multiple lines

Tags: android, arrays, string, android-alertdialog, numberpicker

At the moment I have a NumberPicker that contains an array of String showed by an AlertDialog.

This is the result
[image]

It is possible give to the numberPicker by the setDisplayedValues() method an Array of String where some elements  of this array have a new line?

Actually my array of String is:

```
String[] social = {"Google Plus", "Facebook", "Twitter"};
picker.setDisplayedValues(social);
```

I would like to show the array of string in this way:

```
String[] social = {"Google\nPlus", "Face\nbook", "Twit\nter"};
picker.setDisplayedValues(social);
```

for tho have a result like this:
[image]

I tried to give to the NumberPicker the array of string in the new way, but doesn't work, instead of see a new line I see just a blank space.

Comment: I don't understand. Why don't you just try it? You already obviously have it all coded up. Just try putting those strings in and see what happens...

Comment: i tried doesnt work! it doesnt show the new line but just a blank space

Comment: Just put a lot of empty space between the two words ?

Comment: i think that it's a dirty solution.

Comment: Have you ever found anything to achieve this?

Comment: when writing your own class extending Numperpicker you can define your view, f.e. maxlines=2 and singleline=false.